# MMdrawercontroller menu not closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, mmdrawercontroller

I use the `MMdrawercontroller` in my objective-c application for the left menu.
I have in the navBar a button to open/close the menu. The problem is that the menu is only opened and not closed.
This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)showMenu:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate * app = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:true completion:nil];
  }
```

**EDIT:**
The IBAction is never called when the menu is opened (even if, when I debug, there is no view covering my centerVC)

Comment: have you verified that the code is called when you tap the button while the drawer is open and that app.drawerController is not nil?

Comment: @Aris When I tap the button while the drawer is open, the code is not called at all

Comment: You will need to check to see if something is removing the action from the button when the drawer is shown, or if for some reason you are re-adding the button, without the action.

Comment: @Aris How can I check this please?

Comment: I guess you will have to go through the code and see what happens when the drawer is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I called  below code to reveal menu:

```
#pragma mark- REVEALMENU

- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)revealUnderRight:(id)sender
{
    [self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideRight animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```